# How to add long tap event on div in sencha?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch

I am creating one Image galary which allows user to multi select images and delete them for this I want to add long tap event on my image divs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your div's into Ext.Element instances, see here

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element

Then with the returned Element instance you can attach a longpress event listener

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-longpress